# Creating list of dictionary not working

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, hash

I am trying to create an array of hash in python but it is not working

```
data = ["long","short","fanouts"]
app = []

for da in data:
    app.append(app[name] = da)
```

output

```
File "test.py", line 5
    app.append(app[name] = da)
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Please could anyone help me with correct code i am new to python

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: what do you want to append to `app`

Comment: Why not just `app = data[:]`?

Comment: What is `name` supposed to be ???

Comment: What is "array of has" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
abc(x=y)
```

the interpreter reads that as trying to call a function with a keyword argument. So reading your line

```
app.append(app[name] = da)
```

it thinks you have a keyword argument `app[name]`, which does not make sense as a keyword argument.

If you want to append a dict to your list, you could do it like this:

```
app.append({name:da})
```

as long as `name` and `da` are existing variables.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
data = ["long","short","fanouts"]
app = []

for da in data:
    app.append({name: da})
```

Answer (score -1):

Depends on what you want app[name] to be (assuming app is a dict). Either

```
app[name].append(da)
```

or

```
app.update(name=da)
```

Comment: Wasn't me, but `app` is a list in the op's example.

Comment: Well, it's disputable what app is in the op's example, since it doesn't work. :-) At least to me, it's not perfectly clear that op intended that app be a list. Otherwise, if input and output are lists, where does the dict go? :-)

Comment: True, but I think you should add that `app` is intended to be a dictionary in your answer. :)